# Is Alpha affecting performance on Flex somehow?

Tags: apache-flex, performance, transparency

I am planing to setup all of controls ( more than 100 visible ) on a Flex application to alpha below 1, which will make them a bit transparent, but i am wondering if this will affect the performance of the application. So :

- I would like to know if alpha actually affecting performance on Flex applications ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To add to @Constantiner's answer, every filter and effect (including alpha) will affect performance.  This is the case in any framework you work with... not just Flex.  If you think about it, it makes sense...

You see, without any effects or filters, what gets displayed is straight forward... it is just a pixel.  If the pixel is in front of every other pixel on the Z axis, it gets displayed.  If not, it doesn't get rendered.  No math.  Very easy for the computer to manage.

In your case, you are changing the alpha.  Now, for every pixel in front with an alpha value less than 1, you ALSO have to render to content behind it.  Not only do you need to render the content behind it, you need to blend the pixels in order to get the transparent effect.

Of course, the framework and GPU take care of this work for you... but it comes at a cost.  I am not suggesting that you don't use alphas.  Just know that every time you add an effect or filter (drop shadows, glows, alpha blends, blurs, etc), the system has to do a lot more math for you.  Your frame rate is directly affected by this... but it also produces a much better experience for your user.

Use that knowledge to make an educated decision.  Does the effect/filter add value?  Does the alpha move around a lot like in a scrolling list box (causing re-rendering to happen more often)?  Will this extra overhead be OK?

**EDIT:**
Take a look at this presentation from 360Flex about optimizing Flex performance.  I think it is very useful: http://zaa.tv/2011/06/360flex-denver-2011-flex-performance-tips-and-tricks/

Comment: The things which @BrianGenisio  said is very true when we are speaking about GDI programming on language which result native executive code in windows - like Delphi / Visual C++ or alike - there i am sure the things is like he described. But i tough that Flash have some engine optimisation with it's graphic manipulations :|.

Comment: @Yordan: Well, under the hood, all this math has to happen no matter what.  Yes, the Flash engine is pretty well optimized for this type of work... but something still has to do the work.  If you start playing with alpha values with any type of animation (like scrolling list boxes, for instance), you will find that the frame rate drops significantly.  There are ways to optimize it, but it requires some declaration from you (like bitmap caching, for instance).

Answer (score 2):

Yes, it potentially affects performance. So use it wisely.

I mean if you're using controls with constant background there is no problems with it. But if you have a lot of objects which moves or added/removed to stage often you can have some performance issues.

Comment: Oww. This answer i fear the most. Thank you. :|

Comment: Got any Details?  Or links?  Or any other Background information? Why does the Alpha setting affect performance?  What values of it affect performance?  I tend to think if you're going to have 100 visible controls, the alpha would be the least of your performance concerns.

Comment: @ www.Flextras.com  Of course these problems will not occur if there won't changes in backgrounds (especially if you're using caching as bitmap). But I had some performance issues in the past and since there I try to use alpha wisely. As far as I know Yordan's project from the previous questions he has a lot of pop up windows which can be moved etc. So if alpha is related to these windows there can be problems. Of course it is very difficult to recommend something particular without knowing project's details. Because of every button contains some graphics with alpha (and constant background).

Comment: @www.Flextras.com I've added some details to my answer.